# Which approach is better out of these 2 with react-query fetch?

Tags: reactjs, perf, react-query

To get the maximum benefit of react-query caching which approach is more performant or how could i measure the performance of each data fetching approach with react-query.

Approach 1

```
 <parent />
   useQuery('todos', fetchTodoList)
    <Child1 />
      useQuery('todos', fetchTodoList)
    <Child2 />
      useQuery('todos', fetchTodoList)
    <Child3 />
      useQuery('todos', fetchTodoList)
    <Child4 /> 
      useQuery('todos', fetchTodoList)
```

Approach 2

```
 <parent />
    <Child1 />
      useQuery('todos', fetchTodoList)
    <Child2 />
      useQuery('todos', fetchTodoList)
    <Child3 />
      useQuery('todos', fetchTodoList)
    <Child4 /> 
      useQuery('todos', fetchTodoList)
```

Comment: What's the difference? It's not even valid jsx

Comment: I don't understand the example. Where are the `useQuery` calls happening? Can you try to provide a syntactically valid example please.